# Remap the scroll up command in vim

Tags: vim

I want to remap the Ctrl + y command in vim (scroll up command) to Ctrl + q.
I tried to do
   `:map <C-q> <C-y>`
But it does not seem to work...
Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Your suggested solution works OK for me.

Comment: ctrl-q is a tricky key-bind on linux and windows vim. pls explain what did you mean "does not seem to work", and which OS are you working on?

Comment: well, i am on a linux vim. For example, I am on the line 360 (i can display more than 60 lines on my screen), so I should be able to scroll up. But when i press Ctrl q with my mapping, I do not scroll up, and I dont understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this only affect the Linux terminal (not GVIM), and also Ctrl + S? Then, you need to disable the terminal's flow control commands, by putting the following into your `~/.bashrc`:

```
stty start undef stop undef
```

<sup>PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.</sup>

Comment: Ctrl + S does not work on my terminal and Ctrl Q neither. I tested your command line and it works very well. I will add this in my .bashrc as you recommand. Can you explain a little more what it does exactly?